# splunk query to show counts of fields

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

index=* aa OR bb OR cc
I would like to get an output of fields (aa, bb, cc) and their totals like:

aa   60
bb   45
cc   10

or

aa  bb cc
60  45 10

Answer (score 2):

index=* aa OR bb OR cc | stats count(aa) count(bb) count(cc)

aa bb cc
60 45 10